# how to use any() and all() function in django templates without custom templates tag

Tags: python, django, django-templates

i have some situation where i got python `dict` as **data** which i want to check if any( `any(dict.values)` ) value exist or not.. but not sure how to use `any()` or `all()` function in **django** templates.
is there any built in filter ??

```
 {% if search_result.result.show_more.values %}
              <tr class="header">
                <th colspan="4">{% trans 'Charges Info' %}</th>
              </tr>
 {% endif %}
```

if any value exist in ***showmore*** dict the i want to display header.

Comment: What do you mean "check if any value exists or not". There is always a value for a key, given that a key exists. You can't have a key in a dictionary without a value

Comment: You can have a key in dictionary with empty value like `''` and `any(dict.values())` would return `False`. The question is, do you want to check if there is non-emtpy value in the dictionary, or if there is a key with whatever value set?

Comment: @rollingthedice yeah i know but how we can implement this on django templates ????

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this with custom template tags/filters, something like;

Django Template:

```
{% if values|python_all %}
{% if values|python_any %}
```

Template Tag:

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.filter(name='python_all')
def python_all(values):
    return all(values)

@register.filter(name='python_any')
def python_any(values):
    return any(values)
```

Comment: Mean django doesn't have any syntax. for **al** and **any** method.